# How to do threading in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, function, multithreading, parallel-processing

How to do threading in MATLAB? I want to run one function on two variables simultaneously. How  do I do it?

Comment: @hai: please don't post duplicate questions. If you didn't get answers you liked for your previous question ([admin: now this question]), then you should edit it to make your problem clearer.

Answer (score 7):

The parallel toolbox has some tools that might help you. Find below some example pasted from the Matlab help

```
matlabpool    % Use default parallel configuration
spmd          % By default uses all labs in the pool
    INP = load(['somedatafile' num2str(labindex) '.mat']);
    RES = somefun(INP);
end
```

Then the values of `RES` on the labs are accessible from the client as `RES{1}` from lab 1, `RES{2}` from lab 2, etc.

You might also look at `parfor` as a simple parallel replacement of `for`. Hope this helps even if it's not exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: In R2015a matlabpool function has been removed from Matlab, you need to call parpool instead.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there is any built in multithreading support from MATLAB.
This comes from both a conversation I had with a coworker recently and a [quick google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=matlab+multithreading&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes.  It is one of the problems with using Matlab to produce production apps.

Comment: More and more of Matlab's native functions are multi-threaded with each new release to take advantage of multi-core CPUs.  But the whole philosophy of tools like Matlab is against giving users hands-on access to threads and the like.

Comment: From the Matlab help: There is either "implicit multiprocessing" which makes use of built in multi-threaded functions or "explicit multiprocessing" for which you have to use the parallel computing toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it with MEX files and `std::thread` (see [here](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38034-mexthread)).

I have not tried to call `mexEvalString` from the MEX file, and quite possibly it will result in a runtime error or freeze MATLAB for the time of execution. But if you can write that specific piece of code in C++, it may be what you're looking for.