# How to make a function non-blocking in MATLAB?

Tags: multithreading, matlab, nonblocking

Is there any method to make a function non-blocking in MATLAB?

For example a program

```
for t = 0 : 1 : 1000
    if mod(t, 100) == 0
        foo();
    end
end
```

it called `foo()` every 100 cycles and `foo()` spends about 50 cycles.

I want to call `foo()` in a background task and call a certain callback function when it completes. Is there any method to implement this in MATLAB?

Comment: No, AFAIK there isn't, unless you have the Parallel Processing Toolbox and use the `parfeval` function. If you haven't got the Parallel Processing Toolbox and you want to do something asyncronous, you're using the wrong language. Your only hope is to have `foo()` call some Java, and have the Jave code spawn off some thread or other. Or, consider something like Python (numpy and scipy can make it appear very MatLab-esque), and then you have access to a proper(!) programming language features.

Comment: @bazza I believe that is indeed, the answer. Consider posting it as such.

Comment: @bazza `parfeval` in Parallel Computing Toolbox just meets my requirement, excepting no callback function after `foo()` completed.

Comment: @bazza Your comment looked very nice until the word "proper"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495000/multi-threading-in-matlab

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713218/how-to-do-threading-in-matlab

Comment: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/explicit-multi-threading-in-matlab-part1

Answer (score 1):

to do multi threading in matlab you should use "batch" command (i think you must have parallel computing toolbox),

here is the example :

i like to run a script in matlab which taking long time

example script:

```
for i=1:1e8
   A(i)=sin(i*2*pi/1e8);
end
```

i saved this script as "da" !

then to run it in batch mode i wrote this code in matlab :

```
 job=batch("da")
```

the the job run in batch mode and you could use your matlab simultaneously
t retrieve the results after finishing the job you could simply write :

```
 load(job,'A')
```

and the resulting array A will be at your workspace

you could open "monitor job gui" from Home > Environment > parallel > monitor jobs
and finally you could delete the job with below simple code :

```
 delete(job)
```

to load a function for batch processing you could simply use this statement :

```
 j=batch(fcn, N, {x1,x2,...,xn})
```

where fcn is your function name, N is number of output arrays and x1,...xn are function input arrays.